# Oracle - how to covert xml/clob to human readable varchar

Tags: sql, xml, oracle

There is a clob column binds_xml in oracle's system view `v$sql_monitor`. It has quasi xml format inside like below:

[image]

So I think how to convert such an XML to human readable format something like:

| NAME | POS | DATATYPE | VALUE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| :B1 | 1 | NUMBER | 118904234 |
| :B2 | 2 | NUMBER | 6452822 |

It can be stored in CLOB or VARCHAR - does not matter .

Comment: Why "quasi xml"? Can't you just process that with XMLTable like any other XML? (It would have been helpful to post the original value as formatted text rather than as an image.)

Comment: So what is the idea ? You want for example to have a new column looking like this: ':B1 1 NUMBER 118904234 :B2 1 NUMBER 6452822' ?

Comment: There's no "quasi" XML, it is a pure XML. And XML is already designed to be human-readable. Please describe, how do you want to store a table you showed in a CLOB/VARCHAR and what is the purpose of this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [XMLTable](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/XMLTABLE.html) to process the XML value, extracting the required attributes and value from each `bind` node:

```
select x.name, x.pos, x.datatype, x.value
from v$sql_monitor vsm
cross apply xmltable(
  '/binds/bind'
  passing xmltype(vsm.bind_xml)
  columns name varchar2(30) path '@name',
    pos number path '@pos',
    datatype varchar2(30) path '@dtystr',
    value varchar2(4000) path '.'
) x
order by x.pos
```

| NAME | POS | DATATYPE | VALUE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| :B1 | 1 | NUMBER | 118904234 |
| :B2 | 2 | NUMBER | 6452822 |

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=9f4ad04b5340eff52c59301f8ce13053)

Comment: Alex , thank you very much - perfect solution !